# Worksheet_Change concerning @Scan Excel column for specific word in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have compiled the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S3")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("S3")
        Case "Complete": Sample
        Case "In Progress": InProgress
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The main function of this worksheet change is to read `complete` or `in progress` from a drop down list from cell `S3`. I have a series of drop down lists in a column which all need to perform the about routine but I'm having difficulty to select the whole range in a specific column.

Comment: Change `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S3")) Is Nothing Then` to `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S3:S100")) Is Nothing Then` 100 here is just an example. Replace 100 with the relevant row number. and replace `Select Case Range("S3")` with `Select Case Target.Value`

Comment: You are a genius! :D thanks once again!

Comment: @SiddharthRout glad you helped him, just realized I had pasted one liner instead of the full code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to select the entier column :

`Sheets(1).Range("S:S")`

Then the full code:

```
'-- you can find last used row of your column and used that as well
'-- Dim LastRow as Long 
'-- LastRow = Range("S3").Rows.Count
'-- If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S3").Resize(LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S:S")) Is Nothing Then
    '-- change to proper letter case as if the case don't match then case fails..
    Select Case StrConv(Target.Value, vbProperCase)
      Case "Complete": Sample
      Case "In Progress": InProgress '-- not sure if you need to remove the space
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tristan sorry I realized only a line of teh code has been entered here :$ Glad you got the answer from Siddtharth anyway :)

Comment: + 1 :) You may also use `Ucase(Target.Value)` instead of `StrConv(Target.Value, vbProperCase)` and change the `Case "Complete"` to `Case "COMPLETE"` and similarly with the other :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks :) infact I wanted to use `UCase` but looking at OP's I thought `vbProperCase` would do and didn't want to touch OP`case`. But yeah agree, it's best to keep left and right balanced.